# Stepping Through Visual Studio 2015 -- Different Code Shows Up

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2015

When I press F11 to step through a C++ or C# program in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, I notice that a few steps into main() a completely different set of code shows up.

What I've researched and answers I've been given leads me to understand that this is the framework.

What is the benefit of this? In the future, will making any changes to the framework (if that is in fact what it is) have an impact on my code or my application?

Will disabling this matter? I know in the preferences you can select "Just My Code" under debugging. I'm not sure if that skips the "framework" sections of the step through or not, as I've not had an opportunity to try it.

Any insight or information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

-- TSW

Comment: `F11` is "step *into*". Unless you want the debugger to go into a method call, `F10` to "step over". Enabling "Just My Code" will keep the debugger from stepping into code that is not in your current solution (and acts as "step over" for code that is not yours).

Comment: The only time I've stepped into framework code is to look for a potential bug, It probably won't be useful to you right now.

Comment: Hey, awesome. Thanks!